# regex match start with keyword, end with keyword or newline

Tags: regex

Assume I have this text

**Hi there how are you. This is a test for the root cause of ice cream addiction and not the category of happiness.**

I would like a regex that matches the text the starts with "root cause" and ends with either:

1. the word "category";
2. or a newline
   (whichever comes first).

I've only managed to get as far as (root cause).* but can't figure out how to add the condition for "category" or "newline".

In the above example, I expect to get back "root cause of ice cream addiction and not the".

If I then have a sentence that reads

``Hi there how are you. This is a test for the root cause of ice cream addiction

and not the category of happiness.``

(note the line break), then I expect to get back "root cause of ice cream addiction"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use:

```regex
\broot cause\b.*?(?:\bcategory\b|\n)
```

### Demo

Comment: Thank you. I need to go study what you have pasted there to learn the syntax properly.